# Simple question about pointing out my mistake in denesting this radical

Tags: quadratics, radicals, nested-radicals

Could someone please help me spot my mistake here :

I want to denest $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$, I did the following

$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{d}+\sqrt{e}$

Squaring both sides gives $1+\sqrt{2}=d+e+2\sqrt{de}$

Equating radical and no radicals we get

$1=d+e, \Rightarrow d=1-e$

$\sqrt{2}=2\sqrt{de}\Rightarrow 2=4de \Rightarrow 1/2=de \Rightarrow 1/2=(1-e)e \Rightarrow 1/2=e-e^2 \Rightarrow e^2-e+1/2=0$

Now solving for e we obtain , $e=\tfrac{1^+_-i}{2}$,

which gives $d=\tfrac{1^+_-i}{2}$.

But 1) I read online that when denesting we're always supposed to choose a real e , which is not possible , 2) I don't think d is meant to equal to e is it ?

Comment: What makes you think that denesting is possible?

Comment: @Mindlack I thought I remembered seeing it denested in an example, Is it impossible to denest ?

Comment: Depending on what you allow $d$ and $e$ to be (can they be irrational or nonreal) it may or may not be. Anyway, writing square roots of nonpositive numbers often entails a lot of confusion (and treacherously false properties) so you should be very careful with it.

Comment: A radical of form $\sqrt{a \pm b\sqrt{c}}$ can only be denested into two radicals $\sqrt{x}\pm\sqrt{y}$, if and only if, $\sqrt{a^2-b^2c}$ is a whole number.Here, $\sqrt{1-2}=i$, which is not even a real quantity. Hence denesting is not possible.

If you accept nested complex expressions; then
$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{1-i}}{2}\left(1+\sqrt{2}+i\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, it's better the following way.

Let $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{d}$, where $\{c,d\}\subset\mathbb Q$.

Thus, $$1+\sqrt2=c+d+2\sqrt{cd},$$ which gives
$$(1-c-d)^2+2+2(1-c-d)\sqrt2=4cd.$$
Now, if $1-c-d\neq0$ we obtain $\sqrt2\in\mathbb Q,$ which is a contradiction.

But if $1-c-d=0$ we obtain $2=4cd$, which gives $c\not\in\mathbb Q$ and $d\not\in\mathbb Q$, which is a contradiction again.

Id est, denesting is impossible.

Comment: Why does $2=4cd$ imply that neither $c$ nor $d$ is rational?

Comment: @Jam Try to solve the system: $c+d=1$ and $cd=\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: @Jam Actually, Bath is a beautiful city!

Answer (score 0):

This is curious. Well, for this to be possible we must have $$d+e=1,\,\, de=1/2.$$

From this we get that $(d-e)^2=-1,$ which proves that no such real $d,e$ as we seek exist.

I say it's curious because given any binomial $\sqrt x+\sqrt y,$ where $x,y\ge 0,$ we have, by squaring, $$x+y+2\sqrt{xy}.$$ It doesn't look like anything stops this from being reversed, yet you just provided one counterexample. *I'm curious about knowing what prevents this (I must be missing something obvious).* Could someone please explain?

---

*Addendum:*

> Well, I looked at this a bit more closely, and found that the answer to the question in my third paragraph was already contained in the first.
>
> So, suppose we have the binomial $$\sqrt a+\sqrt b,$$ where $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative rationals, and we want to express its square root as a binomial of the same form. Then if we suppose this to be $\sqrt x +\sqrt y,$ then by squaring the latter and equating to the former, and squaring to remove square roots we obtain the system $$(x+y)^2=a,\,\, 4xy= b.$$
>
> Thus, it must be the case that $(x-y)^2=a-b.$ It follows that a *necessary* condition for us to be able to meet our goal is that $a-b$ be nonnegative. As explained in the first paragraph of this answer, the binomial $1+\sqrt 2$ proposed by OP doesn't meet this condition, hence cannot be written in the desired form. For necessary and sufficient conditions, we'll have to go in cases and I skip it since it's probably not very relevant here.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thanks for the response. But I was asking for *why* this is the case. You did not provide a reason.